# RegEx for prefixed/unprefixed string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to perform a conversion on my XML string by detecting a tag that's always like this:

```
<attr name="firstName" />
<attr name="Name" />
<attr name="lastName" />
```

I wish to catch it and replace it by itself with a suffix so I'll get this:

```
<attr name="firstName" /><attr name="beep" />
<attr name="Name" /><attr name="beep" />
```

But if it's the last one, I wish not to do anything at all.

```
<attr name="lastName" />
```

I'm trying with this detection pattern.

```
Regex.Replace(before, "(<attr name=\"[first]*name\" />)", "[0]<attr name=\"beep\" />");
```

But this will match all permutations of *first*. How can I express *at most one of the exact string "first"*?

Comment: `XML` and `RegEx` is not a good combination

Comment: Agreed. I think RegEx and anything is. But what can you do...   :)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear (or perhaps your goal is). Are you wanting to add the `<attr="beep">` bits, or are you simply trying to replace the sought string with itself (a seemingly pointless endeavor)?

Comment: Seems to me that your proposed changes will break the XML. Why not figure out how to do this with an XML parser instead of splitting your head open with some indecipherable Regex?

Comment: Typo. It's supposed to be `<attr name2="beep" />`.

Comment: I stand by my head splitting statement. Regex and XML should be treated like crossing the beams. Don't do it.

Comment: It seemed like the fastest way to go at the moment. I just want to show in a tag at a position *somewhere* inside another that that's named in two different ways. Suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace(before, "(<attr name=\"[first]?name\" />)", "$0<attr name=\"beep\" />");
```

Replacing the `*` with a `?` will search for either one or zero occurences.

Comment: @CRMconfusee - if you're determined to go down this route - you reference capture groups using `$number`. I don't know where you got `[0]` from. But I'd agree with others - it would be far better to use an XML parser.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet), in the section on patterns.

Comment: @CRMconfusee - and are you accessing the `Matches` collection? Or are you passing a [replacement pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) to `Regex.Replace`?

Comment: Hmmm... Mainly I'm just confusing trying to do the right thing, hehe. Thanks to everybody's hints, I realized that I'm supposed to go $1 not [0]. So the only issue now is that I want to match "first" once or zero times (as opposed to any permutation of "first").

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a negative lookahead:

```
Regex.Replace(before, "(<attr name=\"(?!last)[^\"]*Name\" />)", "$0<attr name=\"beep\" />");
```

To detect zero or one of the string "first", then you can simply change the lookbehind into a normal group that is optional, and replace "last" with "first".

```
Regex.Replace(before, "(<attr name=\"(?:first)?Name\" />)", "$0<attr name=\"beep\" />");
```

Comment: +1 for the best hit this far. Supposing that we can omit the *lastName" risk - how can I match the replacement for the **exact** string *first* (not a permutation of it) **precisely** once or zero times?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
Regex.Replace(before, "(<attr name=\"(?:first)?name\" />)", "$0<attr name=\"beep\" />");
```

`[first]` in a regular expression says "any of the characters `f`, `i`, `r`, `s` or `t`".

`(?:first)` says "the string of characters `first`, treated as a (non-capturing) group". `?` then says that the preceeding match should occur zero or one time.